# Linux FTP proxy product supporting FTPS (FTP-SSL/TLS)

Tags: linux, ssl, proxy, ftp, ftps

I'm wondering if there's any existing FTP proxy product that supports FTP-SSL/TLS that can be used under Linux Redhat environment.

There is a tlswrap however looks like it's been out of maintenance for years.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just finished adding FTPS support to a mod_proxy module for proftpd; it can handle FTPS on the frontend (from clients) and on the backend (to servers), in both forward and reverse proxy modes; see [mod_proxy](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy%20mod_proxy).

*Full disclaimer: I'm the author of `mod_proxy` and ProFTPD.*